# Why I can't import cv2 and other modules to python

Tags: python, opencv, import, pip, conda

I have problem with importing some modules into python.

First of all, I am on MacBook, it's my first OS X device, so maybe I did something wrong.
I installed conda, created main. Everytime I want to work on my python app, I just open terminal, use command: conda activate main, cd into folder and open in VS code. I used pip3 install opencv-python to download this module, It was completed without errors but when I import everything into python file (cv2, tensorflow, matplotlib.pyplot and numpy) and I just

```
try to print Hello, I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zacikm/dev/Python/BC/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2 as cv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Please, help me what can I do to fix this problem. I want to start working on my school project but I'm not able.

Thanks!

---

Sure.

[Picture when I run "pip install opencv-python" under conda env.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxmcX.png)

[Error message what I get after running my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGLd8.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check are you using the right environment after installing the pkg  `pip install opencv-python`.

For example, you are using `base` python rather the conda one.
[image]

Say your conda environment is called `test`.
You need to run

```
conda activate test
```

Then use

```
pip install opencv-python
```

to re-install it for this environment. Then you can use `cv2` in this `test` environment.

Comment: I did pip3 install opencv-python.

Comment: @maiiKy Hi~ did you switch the env?

Comment: I tried, thank you. I activated my main env, installed all required modules but when I open vs code and try to print HelloWorld after importing modules into main.py I still get that error. .. I have activated main env in VSCode but still same error. when I try to pip install again, I get message that already satisfied.

Comment: @maiiKy Can you paste the screenshot?

Comment: I'm not able to post a screenshot here

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found that the solution was to downgrade the opencv version.  In Pycharm, the process is as follows:

1. In Preferences, go to Python interpreter. You will see the current versions of opencv-contrib-python and opencv-python which may be the same as the latest version.
   That is the problem.[image]
2. Double click on the current version of opencv-contrib-python to open this screen:

[image]

3. Check the specify version checkbox and find version 4.1.2.30. Then click Install Package and wait a few seconds to get a message that package was successfully installed. Press OK and you should see opencv-conbtrib-python downgraded to the appropriate version.
4. After step 3, opencv-python may have also downgraded to the appropriate version 4.2.0.34. If it hasn't, follow the same process to downgrade opencv-python to 4.2.0.34.  At the end, your python interpreter screen should look like this:

[image]

That should do it. Test it to make sure it works.